# Delay after commit before Redmine comments ticket

Tags: mercurial, redmine

I was used to having a post-commit hook trigger processing of the commit message by Trac (SVN repository). The comment (or action) was added immediately.

Now I switched to Mercurial as a VCS and Redmine as a ticketing system. Redmine does recognize information in changeset/commit messages like "refs #185" - but it takes several minutes to appear in the ticket.

Any ideas why this is? Is the routine to grab the changesets called periodically somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, [this Redmine feature request](http://www.redmine.org/issues/1274) gives it away:

> Currently, new changeset information is only fetched when you view the repository. So if you update an issue, and mention a revision in it, it doesn't get hyperlinked until someone has viewed the repository.

While I did not find a ready-made post-commit hook to update the Redmine with new changesets, the poor man's solution is cron of course. This questions discusses it:
[Redmine: fetch changesets from cron job](https://serverfault.com/questions/112990/redmine-fetch-changesets-from-cron-job)